# How do I align this text next to the image?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have seen many topics on this around Stackoverflow, but I still could not find out how to do this on this particular case.

I am trying to display a list in a card fashion, I have a template I developed. It looks like this:

[image: Prototype]

Here I have 3 cards, and in the first one, I displayed where I think `divs` should be created

I cannot align the text the way I want. I want the `Title` on top of the `Description` and both aligned right of the first image. But so far I have gotten nowhere. I have a `JSFiddle` of what I have so far right here: http://jsfiddle.net/MEaze/

Sorry about the ugly colors, I just needed to "see" the divs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make them float, and use `div` instead `p`.

```
.trophy-image {
    float: left;
    background-color: #FF0000;
    margin: 8px;
    height: 56px;
}

.trophy-info {
    float: left;
    background-color: #00FF00;
    margin: 8px;
    line-height: 28px;
}
```

[updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MEaze/1/)

Comment: That's exactly it. Perfect :D

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `float:left`

http://jsfiddle.net/cAT2B/
http://jsfiddle.net/y7GJa/
I have also added a second image

You should also use DIV

```
.trophy-image {
    background-color: #FF0000;
    margin: 8px;
    height: 56px;
    float:left;
}

.trophy-info {
    background-color: #00FF00;
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to make the image float left.

I added:

```
float:left;
```

to the image div's css.  Is that what you were looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/2jfSK/

Answer (score 1):

You only have to float the image to left. This div will automatically become a inline-block:

```
.trophy-image {
    background-color: #FF0000;
    margin: 8px;
    height: 56px;
    float: left;
}
```

To set the description to the middle of the image you can use line-height:

```
.trophy-info {
    //background-color: #00FF00;
    line-height: 90%;
}
```

**[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/MEaze/2/)** an example.